# Non-empty IXMLNodeCollection.Count returns 0

Tags: xml, delphi

I have an XSD from a 3rd party and I have used the XML Data Binding tool to generate classes from it. The Data Binding tool did not include the prefix, but I'm able to resolve that in two parts.

1. Adding the prefix `n1` to `TagName` parameter of `GetDocBinding` makes all child elements inherit the prefix *except* child nodes of any `IXMLNodeCollection`. E.g

```pascal
function NewMYDOCUMENT: IXMLMYDOCUMENT;
begin
  Result := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('n1:MYDOCUMENT', TXMLMYDOCUMENT, TargetNamespace) as IXMLMYDOCUMENT;
end;
```

2. Adding the prefix in `AfterConstruction` of any `IXMLNodeCollection`

```pascal
procedure TXMLAllowanceCollection.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('n1:Allowance', TXMLAllowance);
  ItemTag := 'n1:Allowance';
  ItemInterface := IXMLAllowance;
  inherited;
end;
```

With both steps done the XML generated matches the XSD as the 3rd party requires, however I cannot iterate through the elements in the `AllowanceCollection`. `AllowanceCollection.Count` returns 0 regardless of the number of child nodes, and `AllowanceCollection.Allowance[X]` throws an exception even if `X` is a valid index.

If I take out both of the `n1` prefixes from no. 2, the child nodes of the `AllowanceCollection` do not have the `n1` prefix. If I remove only one of them, I get an `EIntfCastError Interface not supported` exception. Including any value in the `NamespaceURI` parameter of `RegisterChildNode` has no effect.

So far I've had to resort to removing the `n1` prefix entirely and overriding `GetXML` to insert the prefix

```pascal
function TXMLMYDOCUMENT.GetXML: DOMString;
begin
  Result := TRegEx.Replace(inherited, '(\<(\/)?)', '\1n1:');
  Result := TRegex.Replace(Result, 'xmlns=', 'xmlns:n1=');
end;
```

Comment: IIRC, the XML Data Binding framework does not support XML namespaces very well.

Comment: Yeah when the XML Data Binding tool generated the classes it left out the namespaces, so I've had to add those in manually. I'm wondering if a potential solution is to remove the namespaces and "manually" add them to the generated XML

Comment: I think you need to update the default generated Data Binding wrappers to utilize the `NamespaceURI` parameter when calling `RegisterDocBinding()` and `RegisterChildNode()`, then you should be able to use prefixes in the node names

Comment: The problem isn't with getting a prefix in the node names, I can do that by putting `abc:` into the name when calling `RegisterChildNode()`. The problem is accessing the elements of the `IXMLNodeCollection` if the collection has a prefix.

I've worked around the issue by removing the namespace and prefix entirely, then inserting the prefix back in to the generated XML string (i.e. replacing `<` and `</` with `<abc:` and `</abc:` respectively)

Comment: like I said, if you register the namespace properly, then you should be able to use prefixes naturally and not have to use a workaround to inject the prefix after the fact

Comment: I'll edit the question to better describe my problem.